# phpize Install xcache in mac os x 10.7.3,no such file directory

Tags: php, xcode, xcache

**When I run phpsize,get the following error:**

```
$ cd /usr/local/xcache-2.0.0
$ phpize
grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:  
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.
```

I have installed xcode 4.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `autoconf` utility to complete the installation. You can install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then do

`brew install autoconf`

in Terminal. After that repeat XCache installation.

I prefer Homebrew because it's easy to use and it puts all its data in /usr/local and doesn't require you to provide sudo password. So it keeps less garbage in your system than for example MacPots.
However, any package manager will help.

UPD:
**Don't forget to check if XCode has Command Line Tools installed**

Comment: Although my question was not solved, still thank you.I'll try other solutions.

Comment: Where did you get xcache? Is it php extension source code? If so why it is placed in /usr/local ? I would expect you unzipping it in ~/Documents/xcache or ~/Downloads/xcache and building from there.
Do this-  Download XCache from http://xcache.lighttpd.net/#Downloads, unpack it, go into dir, run `phpize`, then `./configure` and then `make` and `make install` (of course if previous command succeeds)

Comment: Yea,I have got xcache  from  xcache.lighttpd.net/#Downloads and unzipped. And Copy it to /usr/local/.Through the "CD /usr/local/xcache - 2.0.0" the command go into dir,and run phpize.I used to have such a operation,but faild.

Comment: @slimboy, I recently upgraded to Mountain Lion and experienced the same issue you described. I got it fixed by installing Command Line Tools in XCode (Preferences -> Downloads) and then installing autoconf (I don't think the order makes any difference). After that it all configured fine.

Comment: Yes. I installed Command Line Tools, autoconf and then unpacked extension, made phpize, ./configure and make. All went good. (before installing Command Line Tools phpize complained in the same way you described and failed)

Comment: PHP is system installation or oneself also installed?  Need to install PHP from source?   My PHP is system comes with installation.

Comment: I did it on system PHP install.

Comment: Hehe,I don't know why?   I try it again.  Thank you!

Comment: ＠zysoft,I found the reason.  Because of my xcode not installed Command Line Tools.